# Prove that there do not exist nonzero integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2=3b^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Well, by intuition, of course there is doesn't exist any nonzero integers, but how would you prove that? I was thinking of doing the GCD of $a$ and $b$ is $1$, but that leads me to nowhere.

Comment: Hint:  Write $a=3^mn$ and $b=3^rs$ where $\gcd(3,n)=1=\gcd(3,s)$

Comment: Hint: Use a proof by contradiction. If the square of a/b is indeed 3, what does that say about a and b?

Comment: The exponents of the prime factors of $a^2$ are all necessarily even while those of the prime $3$ in $3b^2$ are necessarily odd. Hence these numbers are distinct.

Comment: @AdrianMungroo If the square of a/b is 3, then a and b are prime??

Comment: @Piquito how do you know $a^2$ have even prime factors and $3b^2$ are odd?

Comment: Not even prime factors but even exponents of the prime factors: the square of $p^n$ is equal to $p^{2n}$ for each prime factor $p$ and $a^2=(\prod p_1^{k_1}.....p_n^{k_n})^2=\prod p_1^{2k_1}.....p_n^{2k_n}$. Hence for $3b^2$ the exponent of $3$ will be odd.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't imply that they are prime. 
It means that a/b is then positive or negative root 3. Let's just take it to be positive. 
You now have a ratio of assumed integers giving you an irrational number, root 3. 
Do you think this makes sense? What conclusions can you make from this?

Comment: I intended this to be a comment, not an answer. My apologies.

Comment: Is OP allowed to assume that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational here?

Comment: Yes indeed; it's like asking if you must assume 1 is an integer.

Comment: How so?  If you are allowed to assume $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, the problem is a complete triviality

Comment: Which it is. But if you want to go the extra mile for completeness, you may include a separate proof by contradiction showing the irrationality of sqrt3.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a rational number, and $x^2$ is an integer, then so is $x$.  Do you see why?

Now if $a^2 = 3b^2$ for integers $a, b$, then $(\frac{a}{b})^2 = 3$, so $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer.  This implies that $3$ is the square of an integer, which it is not.

Comment: Couldn't root 3 squared equal to 3? I get what you're trying to say, but woudn't $(root 3)^2$ get us 3?

Comment: Well $\sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number :) , so no problem there.  That is actually what you must argue here.

Comment: Wait, now I'm a bit confused. $a/b$ is suppose to be an integer, but from the question, we see that $a/b$ is not a integer, but a rational number. What am I not getting?

Comment: It is a priori a rational number, but it *might* also be an integer :) .  For example, $221/13$ is at first glance merely a rational number, but it is in fact an integer.

Comment: Since $(\frac{a}{b})^2$ is equal to $3$, and $3$ is an integer, you have that $(\frac{a}{b})^2$ is an integer. And therefore...

Comment: $(a/b)^2$ is an integer, then $a/b$ is √3, which isn't a rational number nor an integer...oh which means it's impossible for $a$ and $b$ to be integers because there aren't any integers of $a/b$ ratio that could create √3 ? Am i correct?

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{3}$ cannot be expressed as a ratio of integers?  I think that is basically what you have to prove.  I have given you a hint on how to do that (basically, if $\sqrt{3}$ is rational, then it has to be an integer).

Comment: Aha, I have figured how to show that $√3$ is an irrational since if prime $p$, which is 3 in this case, the rational of p is irrational. Then using what you have suggested, I reworked the problem where I found that 3 could divide into $a^2$ and that 3 also could also divide into $b$, but since $a/b$ should be in the simplest form and both $a$ and $b$ are suppose to be coprimes, the GCD of them should be $1$, not $p$, therefore the contradiction. Now that I've proved it and gotten the answer...how would I start answering the question in order to get to these steps?

Comment: I think you are making this too complicated.  Why not follow the steps I gave in my answer, it leads you directly to the solution.